# Считать название изображение из папки

Tags: python, изображения

Необходимо считать из множества папок, названия изображений. То есть есть папка в ней около 60 изображений каждое имет свое название.ImageBlaBlaBla.jpg, так вот нужно создать список где будет написано ImageBlaBlaBla. Пока не понимаю как сделать. Пользуюсь Анакондой. питон 3.

Comment: Файлы из папки считывать используя `glob.glob` или `os.walk`. А что значит каждое название имеет `ImageBlaBlaBla.jpg`? Приведите примеры. Вам нужно просто в список положить все пути к файлам картинок?

Comment: А множество папок - это подпапки одной папки или рабросаны по разным папкам?

Comment: Данную проблему решила таким образом: добавила все папки в winrar, и там  есть возможность после выделения всех файлов сохранить их имена. Всем спасибо!